# Backbone collection different result strategy

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Lets say I have method that returns from server 2 data sets:

On success:

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"id":1, "name": "yolo"}, {"id":2, "name": "yolo2"}]}
```

On fail:

```
{"status":false,"data":["Some error"]}
```

I use following collection:

```
var Entities.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/entity",
    model: Entities.Model,
    parse: function(json) {

        // return different data ?
        // trigger something ?
        return json.data;
    }
});
```

The problem is when I have fail result after fetch it will set collection with error details.

What is the best practice to handle such issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say populate the collection only if you have a success scenario, which would look something like this:

```
var Entities.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "/entity",
  model: Entities.Model,
  parse: function(response) {
    if(response.status)
       return response.data;
    else {} // handle this if you want to do something like triggering an event or
            // setting a flag, else leave it
  }
});
```